# Teacher views or Teacher' views

Tags: possessives

Which is correct when writing a sentence about the views given by teachers?

> Teacher views

or

> Teacher' views

Comment: Neither. "teachers' views."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the views of a single teacher:

> Teacher's views.

For the views of more than one teacher:

> Teachers' views.